# Out of shared memory errors when doing a select query

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, postgresql-performance, database-locking

Using: Postgres 10.2

Ignoring some unrelated columns, I have the table animals with these columns (omitting some unrelated columns):

```
animalid PK number
location (text)
type (text)
name (text)
data (jsonb) for eg: {"age": 2, "tagid": 11 }
```

Important points:

- This table is partitioned, into 1000 child tables.
- Each table could be having around 100,000 records and hence a total of ~100 million records

My application tries to fetch an animal, based on the animalid. For eg:

```
 select "animals"."animalid", "animals"."type", "animals"."data", "animals"."location", "animals"."name" 
 from "animals" 
 where "animals"."animalid" = 2241
```

This though, throws the error (when there are many requests):

```
ERROR: out of shared memory
Hint: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

I would think that the select queries shouldn't be affected by the locks on these tables? Or could it be that queries outside this application can fill up the memory due to the locks acquired on the partitioned tables, thus also affecting the select queries?

I have an option to use the partitioned table directly (as there is a logic to determine it). Could this help in fixing the issue?

Is it generally a good idea to use a bigger value for the max_locks_per_transaction setting, if there are partitioned tables and queries that update them?

My main area of concern is that I do not quite understand why a select query is being affected here. Can anyone help explain?

Comment: Every query acquires a lock on the affect table(s) to prevent concurrent DDL. If you have many partitions, such a lock is acquired for each partition. So increasing max_locks_per_transaction is the correct way to solve this. Although, if you have that many partitions, that your first action should be to upgrade to Postgres 13 as that improved efficiency with that many partitions substantially.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, we will be upgrading soon to latest and until then will also increase the max_locks_per_transaction. But it still doesn't explain why a select query would fail when this happens ? Do you know maybe why?

Comment: Because Postgres looked at **each** partition. Early partition pruning didn't really work with Postgres 10